# dns snap-in fails to sync

Tags: windows, dns, mmc

I use the DNS tool to update DNS on a domain. I log in as a domain admin to one of the domain controllers and use the DNS tool but as of yesterday it doesn't sync to the domain. It only has 10 or so entries. No matter how many times I refresh it is the same. Whenever I open the tool on that domain controller it is the same. If I open mmc and load the DNS snap in, it syncs perfectly. If I log in as administrator or another user or on another computer the DNS tool works fine.

This has happened to me before.

Is there a way of deleting the settings on the DNS tool and getting it to resync?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem. Seems simple but was incredibly annoying. At some point I added a filter to view a subset of DNS entries. The snap-in remembers this filter forever and applies it until you delete it. It wasn't obvious to me that the filter was on.